# Designing WCF Async service with java interop

Tags: java, .net, wcf, interop

I am looking for some feedback on the designing a WCF service, which invokes 2-4 other services and aggregates a response back to the client which is a Java based application. Although the number of requests expected are low, <50 a day max, based on the long running nature of certain calls, I suppose it would be better to design it async but other than marking it async in operationcontract (as below), I am unsure what other features of .NET 4.5 can be leveraged for a scalable design.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService2
{
    //IAsyncResult asynchronous pattern
    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginWorkerMethod(string message, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    string EndWorkerMethod(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

I would appreciate some help in suggestions on the design